# Trouble getting JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Am I missing something or should this work?

```
$weatherAPI = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" . $zipCode . ",us&APPID=myAPI";

$json = file_get_contents($weatherAPI);
$weatherData = json_decode($json,true);

echo $weatherData["main"]["temp"];
```

Comment: Try adding `http://` or `https://` at the front of your URL. Are you getting a specific error? Try `echo`ing $json to see what it contains.

Comment: what errors are you currently getting? you'll probably need to use https:// at the front of the API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least, you must use "http/https" in your URLs:

```
$weatherAPI = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" . $zipCode . ",us&APPID=myAPI";
```

If you will have any problems, provide a JSON response and errors.